# Black box on table

Tags: tables, booktabs

I'm having a really weird problem with a table. I have the following code for two different tables. Table 1's code is the following:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*3c}\toprule
M\'aximo de horas & $R_{P_A}$ & $R_{P_E}$ \\\midrule\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
35  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
37  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
39  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
41  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
43  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
45  & 3.33    & 3.33   \\\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Meanwhile for the second table I have this is the code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{*3c}\toprule
 M\'aximo de horas & $R_{P_A}$ & $R_{P_E}$ \\\midrule\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
35  & 2.08    & 4.580   \\
37  & 2.58    & 4.08    \\\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
39  & 3.08    & 3.58    \\
41  & 3.58    & 3.08    \\\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
43  & 4.08    & 2.58    \\
45  & 4.58    & 2.08   \\\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I'm kind of new to Tex so I don't knwo if this could be caused by any of the packages I'm using, so I'm just going to list all of them right here:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font={color=red},figurename=Figura]{caption}
\usepackage[font={color=red},tablename=Tabla]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xparse}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Curious. A smaller example that demonstrates this is `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[table]{xcolor} \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c} foo \\ \rowcolor[gray]{.95} \end{tabular} \begin{tabular}{c} bar \end{tabular} \end{document}`. By the way, with `\usepackage[table, ... ]{xcolor}`, you don't need `\usepackage{colortbl}`. And you don't need to load `caption` three times either, once is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the last `\rowcolor` directive of the first table influences the first row of the second one. But you should drop it anyway as it has no effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font={color=red},figurename=Figura]{caption}
\usepackage[font={color=red},tablename=Tabla]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*3c}\toprule
M\'aximo de horas & $R_{P_A}$ & $R_{P_E}$ \\\midrule\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
35  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
37  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
39  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
41  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
43  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
45  & 3.33    & 3.33   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
\begin{tabular}{*3c}\toprule
 M\'aximo de horas & $R_{P_A}$ & $R_{P_E}$ \\\midrule\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
35  & 2.08    & 4.580   \\
37  & 2.58    & 4.08    \\\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
39  & 3.08    & 3.58    \\
41  & 3.58    & 3.08    \\\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
43  & 4.08    & 2.58    \\
45  & 4.58    & 2.08   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yeah I was going to, just didn't let me because of the 6 minutes timeline.

Comment: @migueldva Off-topic: you are loading `[utf8]{inputenc}` and yet you type `M\'aximo`. You can go for `Máximo` directly (actually, if you have an up to date installation, you don't even need `[utf8]{inputenc}` anymore, because `utf8` has become the default). If you use this "ascii accents" a lot, that could increase both the readability of your document and ease your typing. (Just make sure your editor saves your document with utf8 encoding).

Comment: Hi @gusbrs, I actually had no idea what  'utf8' was for. TexMaker loads the preamble for me automatically, but it's nice to learn something new. On the other hand, I write the accents that way because I am used to writing with an English keyboard.:)

Comment: That, good Sir, was a real time-saver! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[image: mwe]

Using `\rowcolors` (`xcolor` with `table` option) only one time in the preamble you obtain what you want with cleaner tables (and without black boxes).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!15}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{*3c}\toprule
Máximo de horas & $R_{P_A}$ & $R_{P_E}$ \\\midrule
35  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
37  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
39  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
41  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
43  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
45  & 3.33    & 3.33    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{*3c}\toprule
 Máximo de horas & $R_{P_A}$ & $R_{P_E}$ \\\midrule%\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
35  & 2.08    & 4.580   \\
37  & 2.58    & 4.08    \\
39  & 3.08    & 3.58    \\
41  & 3.58    & 3.08    \\
43  & 4.08    & 2.58    \\
45  & 4.58    & 2.08   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```